# Как создать новый столбец с результатом сравнения других столбцов?

Tags: pandas, сравнение

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'M':[1], 'M1':[1,1],'M3':[1,15],'M4':[1,25],'M5':[1,20]})
```

Как мне создать новый столбец, который будет содержать значение `True`, если скажем `df.M5` будет больше хотя бы одного значения из `df.M1,df.M2,df.M3` или `df.M4`, или `False` если `df.M5` меньше тех значений?

Comment: можете исправить код для примера данных? `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`

Answer (score 2):

Для этого достаточно сравнить `df["M5"]` с максимальным значением каждой строки (исключая столбец `M5`).

Пример:

```
In [399]: df
Out[399]: 
   M  M1  M3  M4  M5
0  1   1   1   1   1
1  0   1  15  25  20
2  1   2   3   4  10

In [400]: res = df.drop(columns=["M5"]).max(axis=1).lt(df["M5"])

In [401]: res
Out[401]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @IgorSorokin, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)